# SDL2 Mouse Position relative to Viewport

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm working on a simple SDL2 application with multiple viewports containing buttons. I'm using the classes from the LazyFoo tutorials, with some minor adaptations (so I'm using LButton from tutorial 17, and I'm using an array of viewports as in tutorial 9).

Here's me setting up my button locations:

```
//Buttons in viewport 1
buttons[0].setPosition(12, buttonHeadSpace );
buttons[1].setPosition(24 + BUTTON_WIDTH_DEFAULT, buttonHeadSpace );
//Buttons in viewport 2
buttons[2].setPosition(12,buttonHeadSpace);
buttons[3].setPosition(24 + BUTTON_WIDTH_DEFAULT, buttonHeadSpace);
```

As you can see, the buttons in viewport 1 have the same values in their position integers as the buttons in viewport 2.

Here's me populating the viewports with buttons:

```
//viewport 1
SDL_RenderSetViewport( gRenderer, &panelOutlines[0]);
buttons[0].render(buttonSpriteSheetTexture, &*buttonSpriteClips);
buttons[1].render(buttonSpriteSheetTexture, &*buttonSpriteClips);

//viewport 2
SDL_RenderSetViewport( gRenderer, &panelOutlines[3]);
buttons[2].render(buttonSpriteSheetTexture, &*buttonSpriteClips);
buttons[3].render(buttonSpriteSheetTexture, &*buttonSpriteClips);
```

And, of course, inside of the LButton object, there is this mouse-hover detection snippet:

```
int x, y;
SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);

//Check if mouse is in button
bool inside = true;
if ( (x < mPosition.x ) || (x > mPosition.x + mButtonWidth) || (y < mPosition.y) || (y > mPosition.y + mButtonHeight) )
{
    inside = false;
}
```

So the problem is that the mouse-hover detection is checking the mouse position relative to the window against the button positions in memory, but the button positions in memory are stored relative to the viewport. So when I mouse over viewport 1 button 1, I get hover animations on viewport 1 button 1 and viewport 2 button 1.

How can I get the mouse position relative to the viewport in SDL2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SDL works with windows, OpenGL's `glViewport` works with portions of the window. Your mouse-hover detection must work with viewports (a simple window-viewport transform), must test all of them until one meets.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to avoid OpenGL, but I might have to start using it eventually here... For the time being I implemented a tree, so it checks collision with the viewport first and then passes relative positions into the button class.